# Can't update MutableStateFlow with model

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-stateflow

I'm trying to update a parameter of my Model. I have a MutableStateFlow with a list with some of my model created.

```
 data class MyModel(
    val id: Int,
    val category: String,
    var completed: Boolean
)
val listOfModel = listOf(
    MyModel(
        id = 0,
       category = "shopping",
        completed = true
    ),  MyModel(
        id = 1,
        category = "web",
        completed = false
    )
)
var _modelStateFlow = MutableStateFlow(listOfModel)
var modelStateFlow = _modelStateFlow.asStateFlow()
```

What I want to do in my other class, is to update the "completed" parameter in the model. That's what I tried but I get the following error:

> Type mismatch. Required: List<"MyModel"> Found: MyModel

```
 _modelStateFlow.update { it[current.value!!].copy(completed = !modelStateFlow.value[current.value!!].completed) }
```

Comment: You have a list of `MyModel`s in your `StateFlow`. In which `MyModel` do you want to change the value of `completed`?

Comment: Change it in the position of the list that the current variable says or change it in all MyModel at the same time. Both options could work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```kotlin
_modelStateFlow.update { list ->
    list.mapIndexed { index, myModel ->
        if(index == indexToUpdate) myModel.copy(completed = !myModel.completed)
        else myModel
    }
}
```

The reason you are getting that error is because, you need to return a new list inside `update` function which represents the new value of `StateFlow`. You can create that new list using `map` function. Update the model at the desired index keeping others as they are.

Comment: And it is posible to update all "completed" parameter of all Models instead for only one?

Comment: Yeah, for that use, `list.map { it.copy(completed = !it.completed) }`

Comment: what about hashmap?